# Como funciona a distribuição dos pontos de reputação?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Estou no Stack Overflow a pouco tempo e não estou entendendo como funciona a distribuição dos pontos de reputação. Existe alguma tabela com a pontuação atribuída a cada participação?

Comment: Tem esta página de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation